# I registered IP DENY on Ubuntu UFW but it does not work

Tags: networking, permissions, iptables, firewall, ufw

182.100.67.235 IP is still connected.
How can I do?

## ufw status

Status: active

```
 To                         Action      From
 --                         ------      ----
```

[ 1] Postfix                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere
[ 2] OpenSSH                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere
[ 3] Apache                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere
[ 4] Apache Full                ALLOW IN    Anywhere
[ 5] Bind9                      ALLOW IN    Anywhere
[ 6] 22                         ALLOW IN    Anywhere
[ 7] Anywhere                   DENY IN     113.10.154.11
[ 8] Anywhere                   DENY IN     218.65.95.159
[ 9] Anywhere                   DENY IN     182.100.67.235
[10] Anywhere                   DENY IN     36.7.87.198
[12] Anywhere                   DENY IN     91.192.197.132
[13] Anywhere                   DENY IN     58.218.198.138
[14] Anywhere                   DENY IN     61.177.172.37
[15] Anywhere                   DENY IN     103.29.16.18
[16] Anywhere                   DENY IN     27.154.242.214

// July 6 additional.

## ufw insert 2 deny 114.143.59.202 to any

ERROR: Wrong number of arguments

## ufw insert 1 deny 114.143.59.202 to any

ERROR: Wrong number of arguments

[ 1] Anywhere                   DENY IN     192.99.3.127
[ 2] Postfix                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere
[ 3] Apache                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere
[ 4] Apache Full                ALLOW IN    Anywhere
[ 5] Bind9                      ALLOW IN    Anywhere
[ 6] Anywhere                   DENY IN     113.10.154.11
[ 7] Anywhere                   DENY IN     218.65.95.159
[ 8] Anywhere                   DENY IN     182.100.67.235
[ 9] Anywhere                   DENY IN     36.7.87.198
[10] Anywhere                   DENY IN     91.192.197.132
[11] Anywhere                   DENY IN     58.218.198.138
[12] Anywhere                   DENY IN     61.177.172.37
[13] Anywhere                   DENY IN     103.29.16.18
[14] Anywhere                   DENY IN     27.154.242.214

```
2018-06-29 12:43:13,861 fail2ban.actions        [860]: NOTICE  [sshd] Unban 182.100.67.235
2018-06-29 12:43:15,227 fail2ban.filter         [860]: INFO    [sshd] Found 182.100.67.235 - 2018-06-29 12:43:15
2018-06-29 12:43:16,860 fail2ban.filter         [860]: INFO    [sshd] Found 182.100.67.235 - 2018-06-29 12:43:16
2018-06-29 12:43:19,565 fail2ban.filter         [860]: INFO    [sshd] Found 182.100.67.235 - 2018-06-29 12:43:19
2018-06-29 12:43:22,270 fail2ban.filter         [860]: INFO    [sshd] Found 182.100.67.235 - 2018-06-29 12:43:21
2018-06-29 12:43:46,159 fail2ban.filter         [860]: INFO    [sshd] Found 182.100.67.235 - 2018-06-29 12:43:46
2018-06-29 12:43:46,509 fail2ban.actions        [860]: NOTICE  [sshd] Ban 182.100.67.235
2018-06-29 12:43:48,971 fail2ban.filter         [860]: INFO    [sshd] Found 182.100.67.235 - 2018-06-29 12:43:48
2018-06-29 12:44:26,521 fail2ban.filter         [860]: INFO    [sshd]     2018-06-29 12:50:44,379 fail2ban.filter         [860]: INFO    [sshd] Found 110.45.147.94 - 2018-06-29 12:50:43
2018-06-29 12:50:46,267 fail2ban.filter         [860]: INFO    [sshd] Found 110.45.147.94 - 2018-06-29 12:50:46
2018-06-29 12:50:48,160 fail2ban.filter         [860]: INFO    [sshd] Found 110.45.147.94 - 2018-06-29 12:50:48
2018-06-29 12:50:50,635 fail2ban.filter         [860]: INFO    [sshd] Found 110.45.147.94 - 2018-06-29 12:50:50
2018-06-29 12:52:22,118 fail2ban.filter         [860]: INFO    [sshd] Found 91.236.178.157 - 2018-06-29 12:52:22
2018-06-29 12:52:22,118 fail2ban.filter         [860]: INFO    [sshd] Found 91.236.178.157 - 2018-06-29 12:52:22
2018-06-29 12:52:23,802 fail2ban.filter         [860]: INFO    [sshd] Found 91.236.178.157 - 2018-06-29 12:52:23
2018-06-29 12:53:03,902 fail2ban.filter         [860]: INFO    [sshd] Found 164.132.202.47 - 2018-06-29 12:53:03
2018-06-29 12:53:03,905 fail2ban.filter         [860]: INFO    [sshd] Found 164.132.202.47 - 2018-06-29 12:53:03
2018-06-29 12:53:05,932 fail2ban.filter         [860]: INFO    [sshd] Found 164.132.202.47 - 2018-06-29 12:53:05
2018-06-29 12:53:47,343 fail2ban.actions        [860]: NOTICE  [sshd] Unban 182.100.67.235
2018-06-29 12:54:04,592 fail2ban.filter         [860]: INFO    [sshd] Found 182.100.67.235 - 2018-06-29 12:54:04
2018-06-29 12:54:06,197 fail2ban.filter         [860]: INFO    [sshd] Found 182.100.67.235 - 2018-06-29 12:54:05
2018-06-29 12:54:08,903 fail2ban.filter         [860]: INFO    [sshd] Found 182.100.67.235 - 2018-06-29 12:54:08
2018-06-29 12:54:11,174 fail2ban.filter         [860]: INFO    [sshd] Found 182.100.67.235 - 2018-06-29 12:54:11
2018-06-29 12:54:49,935 fail2ban.filter         [860]: INFO    [sshd] Found 182.100.67.235 - 2018-06-29 12:54:49
2018-06-29 12:54:50,036 fail2ban.actions        [860]: NOTICE  [sshd] Ban 182.100.67.235
```

Comment: Working or not?

Comment: 192.99.3.127 is number 1, but it will start from the next.
# ufw insert 1 deny 114.143.59.202 to any
ERROR: Wrong number of arguments

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The order of the firewall rules is important. Since you have allowed 80 for all at the beginning, this rule will match for all request and the deny rule that comes later will never be matched.

So, if you need to block something *particularly*, put it at the beginning and then *allow all*.

To see your rules with a reference number, use this:

```
sudo ufw status numbered
```

Then remove the deny rule first that you have added:

`sudo ufw delete rule_number_here`

Then add it again at the top:

```
sudo ufw insert 1 deny from xx.xx.xx.xx to any
```

Comment: Now it is very good.
But,
I can not continue adding IP.
I added an additional post in the body.